# Random 'Undefined' Error

Tags: actionscript-3

I am a beginner in ActionScript 3, I am trying to traverse an array of MovieClips and pick hundred random Clips out of that and place those instances on stage but sometimes the code produce an undefined error. I am confused why as the code works well most of the times and there are never any compile time errors.

Here is my code:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i<100;i++)
{

   var rndNum:Number = Math.round(Math.random()*arr.length);
   this.addChild(arr[rndNum]);
}
```

Comment: Since AS3 arrays are zero-based, might it be that the error is caused by `Math.random()*arr.length` being rounded up to `arr.length` which is outside of the range of the array? Could you try confirming whether this is the case?

Comment: Yup that exactly was the case. Thanks Esa :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are rounding the randomly generated index which could result in an index out of bound Exception, and that is because you are generating a number up to the array's Length and the number representing the total length of an array can never be a valid index for that Array since the index starts at 0.

Simply change the `Math.round` to `Math.floor`

```
var rndNum:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length);
```

or do a -1 from the arr's length:

```
var rndNum:Number = Math.round(Math.random()*(arr.length-1));
```

Comment: var randNum:int = Math.random() * arr.length;  Also technically, using a uint is the right choice as an array cannot have a negative index. The int or uint declaration for the variable will chop off the decimal places which is the same as rounding down with floor.

Comment: Just wanted to add that note as using Number for this case is creating the need for rounding and adding complexity that is not needed.

Comment: Thanks prototypical, I fixed that too :)